# database error Subquery returns more than 1 row in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

hallo i want to query in codeigniter and return 1 row but i get error return more than 1 row.
this is modal

```
function get_status_pendaftaran_anggota()
    {
        $this->db->where("nim",$this->session->userdata('nim'));
        $this->db->where("id_periode = (SELECT id_periode from periode 
            where tgl_dari <= CURDATE() AND tgl_sampai >= CURDATE())");
        $row = $this->db->get('pendaftaran_ukt');

        if ($row) {
            return $row->row();
        }
        else
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

how to solve this.

thank you

Comment: what is the need of subquery can you elaborate what you are trying to achieve

Comment: id_periode **IN** (...

Comment: Please let us know whether your query is right or wrong?

Comment: Instead of equal you have to use IN clause like d_periode IN

Answer (score 0):

Lets you limit the number of rows you would like returned by the query:

```
$this->db->limit(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

1) As said by ***Hamlet***, add **`IN`** after `id_periode`.
2) Also when using **`raw queries`**, add NULL and FALSE as additional **`parameters`**.
 3) **`NULL`** says you are not passing any data to where clause (ofcourse since it is raw query).
4) **`FALSE`** will not try to protect your field or table names with backticks.

```
function get_status_pendaftaran_anggota()
{
    $this->db->where("nim",$this->session->userdata('nim'));
    $this->db->where("id_periode IN (SELECT id_periode from periode 
        where tgl_dari <= CURDATE() AND tgl_sampai >= CURDATE())", NULL, FALSE);
    $row = $this->db->get('pendaftaran_ukt');

    if($row->num_rows() > 0)
    {
        return $row->row();
    }
    else
    {
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

try this.

```
 if ($row->num_rows() > 0) {
        return $row->row_array();
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
```